# Floyd-Warshall algorithm implementation with list of lists

Tags: java, algorithm, matrix, floyd-warshall

I want to use the Floyd-Warshall algorithm to find the shortest path between two vertices. The matrix is in an ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>. It is always fairly small, such as a 4x4 or 8x8 matrix.

In my class, I have a distance matrix already. I'm just trying to create the "shortest path" matrix. But it doesn't work. It fills my matrix wrong.

I really hope someone can look at this and explain what's wrong.

My distance matrix is:

```
 0   0  256 411
556  0  558  0
250  0   0  431
 0   0  431  0
```

Test output is:

```
 0   0   0   0 
556 556 556 556 
250 250 250 250 
 0   0   0   0
```

Expected:

```
500 0 842 681
556 0 806 967
 0  0 500 681
581 0  0  862
```

I've commented out my test output. `distance` is my matrix with the integer value of the distances between the vertices. In my matrix, `i` is y and `j` is x.

```
public ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> calcShortest() {
        //String test = "";
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> shortest = distance;

        for (int k = 0; k < airports.size(); k++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < airports.size(); i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < airports.size(); j++) {
                    shortest.get(j).add(i, Math.min(shortest.get(k).get(i) + shortest.get(j).get(k), 
                            shortest.get(j).get(i)));
                }
            }
        }
        /*for (int j = 0; j < airports.size(); j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < airports.size(); i++) {
                test += shortest.get(j).get(i) + " ";
            }
            System.out.println(test);
            test = "";
        }*/
        return shortest;
    }
```

Comment: I have no idea on what is Floyd Warshall algorithm, but can you tell us how to get the expected matrix using basic operations ?

Comment: Wikipedia: "the Floyd–Warshall algorithm is an algorithm for finding shortest paths in a weighted graph", so it will fill in the shortest path, for eg it will check the shortest path from a to c, it will find its faster go over d instad of b and will fill in the shortest distance, when there is a path aviable. Im using a directed graph so thats why it might look weird at the beginning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of problems with your code and your data.

- The `add` operation `shortest.get(j).add(i, ...)` inserts an element into the `ArrayList`. You actually want to set a value: `shortest.get(j).set(i, ...)`
- The array indices are wrong. You're trying to do `shortest[j][i] = min(shortest[k][i] + shortest[j][k], shortest[j][i])`, but Floyd-Warshall calls for `shortest[i][j] = min(shortest[i][k] + shortest[k][j], shortest[i][j])`.
- Your expected output doesn't make sense. How is it possible for `shortest[2][2]` to be 500? We already know that it's 0. And how do you figure that `shortest[3][0]` is 581? There is no way to get 581 from the distance matrix that you've given.
- In the distance matrix, why do you have zero values off the diagonal? For example, `distance[1][3]` is 0. So the distance from node 1 to node 3 is 0? Really?
- Why are you making `shortest` refer to `distance`? Since you're modifying `distance`, why not just use `distance` instead of pretending that you have a different matrix called `shortest`? Or did you intend to make a copy of `distance`?

The code below runs Floyd-Warshall correctly because it calls `set` to modify the `ArrayList` and it uses the correct indices. However, it does not produce what you call the "expected" result for your distance matrix because, as I have explained, your expected result doesn't make sense and the distance matrix itself is suspect.

```
  int n = shortest.size();
  for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) { 
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { 
      for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) { 
        shortest.get(i).set(j,
            Math.min(shortest.get(i).get(k) + shortest.get(k).get(j), 
                     shortest.get(i).get(j)));
      } 
    } 
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer it really helped me ! I should have said its a directed graph, so you will maybe, be able to get from a to b, but not from b to a. Sorry for letting that out. I did intend to make a copy of the matrix distance, since i will be using it seperatly and might need only the distance after i checked for the shortest route. 
It didnt solve my problem instantly so i checked everything again. And found out that i inserted in my distance matrix, 0 instad of INFINITY, so ofc it wont work when I check for minimum and I have zeros everywhere.
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 shortest.get(j).add(i, Math.min(shortest.get(i).get(k) + shortest.get(k).get(j), 
                        shortest.get(i).get(j)));
```

Or use Dijkstra's algorithm